# Don't understand the result of these max and min functions

Tags: python

Basically I have been tasked with outputting the max and min values of this list: {"a": 43, "b": 1233, "c": 8}, where the correct output should be

```
min: c
max: b
```

While I have already solved this, I have learned that another solution is much more concise:

```
print('min:', min(test_dict, key=test_dict.get))
print('max:', max(test_dict, key=test_dict.get))
```

Main problem faced here is that I don't understand how the min and max functions work like that, shouldn't its arguments only take in integers? Also what is key = test_dict.get?

Comment: It finds key with maximum and minimum value. `key` here specifies that you want min and max to perform on values and get the corresponding key.

Comment: You can see [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max). It says “ The `key` argument specifies a one-argument ordering function like that used for list.sort().”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument can be a sequence of any type of data.

`min` and `max` will iterate over the elements of the sequence, calling the `key` function on each of them, and then return the element where the value of the function is minimized or maximized.

When you iterate over a dictionary, the elements are the dictionary keys. `test_dict.get(x)` returns the element of `test_dict` whose key is `x`.

So `min(test_dict, key=test_dict.get)` will iterate over the keys of `test_dict`, and for each of them it will call `test_dict.get()`, which returns an integer. It will then return the key with the minimum value.

Answer (score 1):

**key** is a parameter of the min/max function, which makes python know how to compare two element in test_dict.

`test_dict.get` is a function, and it receives one parameter key, and returns the value in test_dict. So when the `min` or `max` function compares two element, for example, "a" & "b":

- compare "a" and "b" -> compare test_dict.get("a"), test_dict.get("b") -> 43, 1288.

Hence "a"<"b".

Answer (score 0):

You want to use ".values()", otherwise it defaults to keys

dict={"a": 43, "b": 1233, "c": 8}
print(max(dict.values()))